# grep only one occurrence

Tags: linux, shell, unix, grep

I am trying to grab some content, but there are multiple instances of it in the same line. I am using this command.

```
grep -o -m 1 -P '(?<=sk).*(?=fa)' test.txt | head -1
```

However, the search ends after the second/last match. Running it on Ubuntu 14.04.2

```
test.txt: skjahfasdkl aklsdj laks skjahfasdkl aklsdj laks
Current Output: jahfasdkl aklsdj laks skjah
Desired output: jah
```

Comment: Just pasted the sample data and the current output.

Comment: it's greedy finding the longest match from first "sk" to last "fa"

Comment: So you have just one line in input file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need non-greedy:

```
grep -m1 -oP '(?<=sk).*?(?=fa)' file | head -1
# ...................^^^
```

The `-m1` will stop after the first *line*, but you still need `head` to limit to the first *match*.

Comment: Nothing less than perfect. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's greedy match, you want to treat space as delimiters so specify the match to nonspace chars, i.e.

```
    ... '(?<=sk)[^ ]*(?=fa)'
```

Answer (score 1):

if the condition is non spaces between sk and fa ( matching in words ), you can use can use [^ ]* instead .*,  as the following:

```
grep -o -m 1 -P '(?<=sk)[^ ]*(?=fa)' test.txt | head -1
```

else you can use this :

```
sed -e "s/sk\(.*\)fa.*$/\1/g" test.txt | sed -e "s/fa.*$//g"
```

test :

```
echo "skjahz z zfasdkl aklsdj laks skjahppppfasdkl aklsdj laks" | sed -e "s/sk\(.*\)fa.*$/\1/g" | sed -e "s/fa.*$//g"

#jahz z z
```

Answer (score 1):

If you consider non-grep answer then this gnu-awk can do the job:

```
awk -v FPAT='sk[^[:blank:]]*fa' '{gsub(/^sk|fa$/, "", $1); print $1; exit}' file
```